# Wordpress - How to show posts in grid style on search result page?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show posts in a grid-style layout on the search result page when someone searches for something using the search bar. Right now it is showing a list-style layout. I also want to hide the "excerpt" and "continue reading" button. Website link - http://test123.42web.io/

Answer (score -2):

you need to build a elementor template for search results pages.

1. install elementor custom skin
2. make a single grid post
3. make a loop of that post and include it in search results template
   done!